# How to filter list values from corresponding index names located in list?

Tags: python, list, filtering

I have a trivial question, as seems so, but I am not able to see the simplest solution. I have a list of lists:

```
Example_list=[[['MAX_BID', '€9'], ['BID_NUMBER', 10], ['DATE', '2017-01-25 20:10:33 UTC'], ['SHIPPING_COST', '17.90']], 
[['MAX_BID', '€165'], ['BID_NUMBER', 30], ['DATE', '2017-01-25 20:12:01 UTC'], ['SHIPPING_COST', '16.00']]]
```

Now I simply want to filter the value for BID_NUMBER in the second list. Obviously the following works:

```
>>> print(test[1][1][1])
30
```

Unfortunately, this will not be a solution as the real case has lists of varying size resulting in different locations for the desired list value.

I have also tried the following but it seems like its not the most simple solution:

```
for i in test[1]:
    for p in i:
        if "BID_NUMBER" in p:
            print(p[1])
30
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: The first list has 3 levels is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all sub-lists in each immediate sub-list are key-value pairs, you can convert the enclosing list to a dict before accessing `BID_NUMBER` as a key:

```
for d in map(dict, test):
    print(d['BID_NUMBER'])
```

Otherwise, if the depth of such sub-lists of key-pairs are inconsistent, you can use a `while` loop to keep going for the inner sub-list in an `except` block after trying to convert the sub-list in a `try` block:

```
for l in test:
    while True:
        try:
            d = dict(l)
            break
        except ValueError:
            l = l[0]
    print(d['BID_NUMBER'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, for now this results in the following error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required

Comment: I see. So the sub-lists in your input really are of inconsistent depths. You should try fixing the logic of whatever produces such bad data, or if you don't have the rights to, you can use the other solution in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your additional explanation where you explain what to do with inconsistent sub-lists! Works like a charm.

Comment: There was a bracket error in the use-case example, resulting in inconsistent depths. The real case data doesn't have the inconsistent depth, and your first solution works. I have edited the top post and now your original solution also works as a charm. Thanks!